# Edittext scrolling inside Recyclerview and NestedScrollView android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

I have an edittext which is of inputType textMultiLine inside RecyclerView which again is in NestedScrollView. I have a functionality in which I have to take Recyclerview inside the NestedScrollview. RecyclerView scrolling has been disabled by NestedScrollingEnabled as false. Inside this Recyclerview, there is an itemtype which has edittext in it. This edittext is Multiline and of 100 dp, If vertically, the content won't fit, the content will get cut, cause of max height. So How can I make my edittext scrollable inside Nested Scroll View

I have enabled Edittext scrolling with the following code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etYesDescription"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

But it is still not scrollable, How can I make my Edittext scroll work?

Comment: not getting exactly.add some more details.

Comment: Edited the question. Please check

Comment: i post the ans have look and apply, hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve by this programmatically have look

```
 EditText etYesDescription= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etYesDescription);
 etYesDescription.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.comment1) {
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is helped me.

Comment: How do this convert to if?